# How do I stop opening a .whl file with the notepad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, file-rename

I have accidentally changed my Pygame .whl to open with the notepad. This means I get this error when trying to install the Pygame.

I tried, hopelessly, typing ".whl" at the end of the file when renaming, however it did not work.

```
C:\Users\ronald>cd Downloads

C:\Users\ronald\Downloads>pip install pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\ronald\downloads\pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ronald\\Downloads\\pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual path is most likely `pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl.txt`

What you need to do is remove the `.txt` but you most likely have file name extensions unchecked so you can't just rename the file.

In windows explorer you need to click on the View tab then mark the check box that says `File name extensions`. This will show the file extensions on all files and allow you to change them.

After that just remove the `.txt` and you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commandline.

Hit <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> , enter `CMD`, hit <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd>: this will open the command-line-interface-shell-thingy.

Issue the commands ( one per line, close with <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> ):

```
c:\
cd C:\Users\ronald\Downloads\
dir pygame*.*

move pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl.txt  pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl 
dir pygame*.*
```

This will:

- change to your C drive
- change into the subdirectory
- list all files beginning with pygame
- rename the file back to what it should be
- and list the files again to check

Hit <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> after each line above.

If in the first listing the file is different from `pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl.txt` you need to give that name in the `move ...from...  ...to...` line.

---

Or you simply download the correct file again.